# Configure issues with Vlans & Firewalls

Tags: routing

I hope someone can shed light on what I need to do with this newrok configuration issue.   Hope I explain it as well enough also.  I have included a basic diagram of how things are connected for reference.

Existing network made up of about 10 switches over 2 buildings.   We use Brocade switches, layer 3 and about 15 different VLANS.  We have/had a single firewall and a 100 Meg pipe to the internet that we are replacing.  All my VLANS are setup on my core switch.

Example config for all VLANS.  We basically keep the 3rd octet as the VLAN number for refereance.

```
*VLAN 115 Workstations Main Building
VE interface 115
(tagged trunk ports)
.
.
Interface VE 115
IP Address 10.10.115.1 255.255.255.0
IP helper-address 1 10.10.50.114
*
```

**New Configuration:**   New 500 Meg. pipe connected to  2 WatchGuard M400 Firewalls to use in an active/passive failover mode.   On the WatchGuard.
Port 1 - External and has our public IP number
Port 2 - Trusted VLAN
Port 3 - Trusted with an ip of 10.10.10.2/24

Now for the issue:
When configuring VLANS on the WG they require a gateway that sits on the WG.   So, for VLAN 115, I can not add the gateway of 10.10.115.1.   I can add 10.10.115.2, but traffic does not get there.

Need more info, please ask as I have spent over a week on this one and my only progress is konwing what does not work.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Kenny

What am I missing?   I also have a much more detailed Visio drawing if needed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXD2H.png)

Comment: I am confused. If you are using the switches as layer-3 switches, you should be connecting them with routed links, not trunks. Access interfaces (where the workstations connect) should be assigned to VLANs, but the frames should not be tagged on access interfaces, only tag frames on trunk interfaces.